# How can i use variable value inside function selected from select dropdown outside the function and assign it to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have below HTML and JavaScript code

```js
function changeResult() {
  x = document.getElementById("dropdown-list").value;
  console.log((x));
}
var qq;
```

```html
<select id="dropdown-list" onchange="changeResult()">
  <option value="499">Below $500</option>
  <option value="999">Below $1000</option>
  <option value="1499">Below $1500</option>
</select>
```

I have to assign variable x to qq.
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Does this help? [Return values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values)

Comment: @user1599011 The return value of an `onchange` function isn't used, so how would that help?

Comment: Change `x=` to `qq=`.

Comment: You could also just use `onchange="qq = this.value"`

Answer (score 0):

Try var to introduce your `qq` global variable:

```js
var qq = 499;
function changeResult(){
  qq=document.getElementById("dropdown-list").value;
}
function showQQ() {
  console.log(qq)
}
```

```html
<select id ="dropdown-list" onchange="changeResult()">
  <option value="499">Below $500</option>
  <option value="999">Below $1000</option>
  <option value="1499">Below $1500</option>
</select>

<button onclick="showQQ()">Show QQ</button>
```

Comment: They're already using `var` to declare the variable.

Comment: Its not yet global .